# Insert into bucketed table produces empty table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, orc

I`m trying to do insert into bucketed table. When I run the query everything looks fine and I see in reports some amount of wrote bytes. No any errors in Hive logs also.
But when I look into table I have nothing :(

CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `test_date` string,
  `test_id` string,
  `test_title` string,)
CLUSTERED BY (
  text_date)
INTO 100 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION
  'hdfs://myserver/data/hive/databases/test.db/test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1',
  'transactional' = 'true')

INSERT INTO test.test
SELECT 'test_date', 'test_id', 'test_title' from test2.green

Result
Ended Job = job_148140234567_254152
Loading data to table test.test
Table test.teststats: [numFiles=100, numRows=1601822, totalSize=9277056,   rawDataSize=0]
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 6  Reduce: 100   Cumulative CPU: 423.34 sec
HDFS Read:   148450105
HDFS Write: 9282219
SUCCESS

hive> select * from test.test limit 2;
OK
Time taken: 0.124 seconds
hive>

Answer (score 1):

Is this query really working? You have extra comma after in line

```
test_title string,)
```

also coulmn  text_date isnt in your you column definition. May be you meant test_date?

```
CLUSTERED BY (text_date)
```